# MailKit - Get email body as text excluding chains

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I am using MailKit in C# to read from my Mail Inbox. I am trying to get the body just a plain text but I can't quite figure out how I do that. I will share the code I have so far.

Essentially I need to store that body text as a string in the database but I can only get the HTML version currently.

```
List<MimeMessage> mimeMessages = new();

                ImapClient imapClient = new();
                imapClient.Connect(mailSettings.ImapServer, mailSettings.ImapPort, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                var password = _encryptHelpers.DecryptString(mailSettings.Password);
                imapClient.Authenticate(mailSettings.Email, password);
                imapClient.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                var uids = imapClient.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(lastChecked));
                var messages = imapClient.Inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Body | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);

                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    var mailMessage = imapClient.Inbox.GetMessage(message.UniqueId);
                    mimeMessages.Add(mailMessage);
                }

                imapClient.Disconnect(true);

                return mimeMessages;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could use

```
foreach (var message in messages) {

     // IMessageSummary.TextBody is a convenience property that finds the 'text/plain' body part for us
     var bodyPart = message.TextBody;

     // download the 'text/plain' body part
     var body = (TextPart)imapClient.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, bodyPart);

     // TextPart.Text is a convenience property that decodes the content and converts the result to a string for us
     var text = body.Text;
}
```

This sample is taken from http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_MessageSummary_TextBody.htm

Comment: Yeah I've seen that a couple times but my message.textBody is null so it just keeps erroring because of that

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but I got the same problem and maybe I can help.

@Marco's answer works well also for me, but only if the body of the mail is "plain text".

If the body of the mail is HTML, message.TextBody is NULL, but it's pretty easy to check if message.HtmlBody is not NULL and process it in the same way.

So you could do:

```
if (message.TextBody != null)
{
    plain = (TextPart)imapClient.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.TextBody);
    body = plain.Text;
}
else if (message.HtmlBody != null)
{
    plain = (TextPart)imapClient.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.HtmlBody);
    body = plain.Text;
}
```